# HTTP2 support for Traefik ingress in Kubernetes (K3S)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, traefik, k3s

I use [K3S](https://k3s.io/) for my Kubernetes cluster. It's really fast and efficient. By default K3S use [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) for ingress controller which also work well til now.

The only issue I have is, I want to have HTTP2 server push. The service I have is behind the ingress, generates [Link header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link) which in the case of [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) I can simply turn it into the HTTP2 server push (explained [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-9-http2-server-push/)). Is there any same solution for Traefik? Or is it possible to switch to NGINX in K3S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP2 Push **not** supported in Traefik yet. See the github open issue [#906](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/906) for progress on the matter.

Though, you can safely switch to the nginx ingress controller to accomplish HTTP2 push

a) `helm install stable/nginx-ingress`

b) in your ingress yaml set appropriate annotation

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

Comment: Based on 906 and the crumb trail Traefik will not support HTTP/2 Server Push because it's a Webserver feature and [not appropriate for Traefik](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/6129#issuecomment-676405438). Server Push is however being added as a community plugin. See link for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about that HTTP2 in traefik, but you can simply tell k3s not to start traefik and deploy your choice of ingress controller:

https://github.com/rancher/k3s#traefik

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want HTTP/2 Server Push given it's [being removed from Chromium](https://brianli.com/2020/12/chrome-to-drop-support-for-http2-server-push/). If you would like to switch ingress controllers you can choose another by:

- Starting K3s with the `--disable traefik` option.
- Adding another controller such as NGINX or Ambassador

For detailed instructions on adding Ambassador to K3s see the following link: https://rancher.com/blog/2020/deploy-an-ingress-controllers